# How to run android app (.apk) inside a docker container without emulator

Tags: android, docker

I want to run android apps inside a docker container to run them on Linux. I know there are ways to run android apps using some tools like [Anbox](https://anbox.io/) or [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) but these tools take too much memory and make the other apps very slow.

I have tried to run them inside a docker container like [this](https://github.com/budtmo/docker-android) but the problem is, I was able to run .apk only inside an emulator which again is slow. Is there a way to run .apk directly on Android OS (without emulator) inside a container?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't run a different OS in your container then the one running in your host machine.